# Implementing CSRF in Rest based Springboot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

I have a use case where I need to integrate the CSRF into a Springboot application.
The scenario is:

- I have a Rest based Springboot application (Not MVC based)
- User will login in that application using Username and password.
- We need to provide the CSRF token to user using Spring's Security.
- This application needs to be deployed into multiple different instances to support scalability.
- We are using stateless (or self managed user's session in DB)

Based on my research we need to make use of Custom CSRF Repository to support the CSRF Validation.

But I didn't get the few following scenarios:

- So, Is this understanding right: Will Spring automatically calls the `saveToken()` (from Custom CSRF Repository) at the user's login attempt ?
- If yes, is there any way to tell Spring which Rest API endpoint is
  the Login Rest API like `/custom-login` ?
- If no, what is the correct way to do it ?
- When will `generateToken()` (from Custom CSRF repository) will be called and how it can be associated with User ?

Comment: Spring Security does already do CSRF why would you want a custom implementation?

Comment: Hey @M.Deinum,

As mentioned in question, we are planning to use Custom Implementation to support multi-instance support.
As default one uses Spring's Session

Comment: You shouldn't need a custom implementation. Use the `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` so it gets stored in a cookie and send in a header.

Comment: So, I guess my understanding is wrong.
Then do we need to associate CSRF token with User's Identity ?

Comment: No. Those things aren't related and serve different purposes.

Comment: And how it is shared with multiple instances ?

Comment: It doesn't need to if it is in a cookie.

Comment: Will try this out, and post the status here